# Can you copy an Azure VM from one account to another account?

Tags: azure, copy, virtual-machine

We created a VM for a client and set it all up on our account. A bunch of work. Now I'd like to put a copy of it on his Azure account (which he does not have yet) and keep my copy for troubleshooting. Is there a method I can use to backup the VM and restore it to his Azure account? Or any other suggested way to copy it to another account's VM?

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can. Since VHD for your Virtual Machine is stored as `Page Blob` in Azure Storage, you can simply copy the blob from one storage account to another. You can use [`AzCopy`](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/storage-use-azcopy/) tool to do that. There's no need for you to download the blob from main storage account and reupload it in backup storage account.

When you need to create a VM again, simply create an image using that blob and then create a VM from that image.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Image and upload to the new account, You can check link for more information [Create and upload a Windows Server VHD to Azure](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-create-upload-vhd-windows-server/)